# landscape client won't register

Tags: server, dns, connection, landscape, client

I am attempting to connect a client to my new landscape server. One client has already successfully connected, this one has given me issues. The string I am using to enroll it is
`sudo landscape-config --computer-title "client-name" --account-name standalone  --url https://server-name/message-system --ping-url http://server-name/ping --ssl-public-key /etc/landscape/server.pem`.
 This is the same string that was successful last time. The error message I receive is 
`We were unable to contact the server.
Your internet connection may be down. The landscape client will continue to try and contact the server periodically.`
Using the following curl statement, I can tell the connection to the server should be fine, though it does seem to hang when resolving the name.
`curl https://server-name/ping --cacert /etc/landscape/server.pem`
What can I do to get this client connected to my landscape server? Below is the relevant last few lines of the broker.log file:
`sudo tail -n 12 /var/log/landscape/broker.log
2018-06-25 07:30:55,477 INFO     [MainThread] Starting urgent message exchange with https://server-name/message-system.
2018-06-25 07:31:06,996 ERROR    [PoolThread-twisted.internet.reactor-0] Error contacting the server at https://server-name/message-system.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/broker/transport.py", line 71, in exchange
    message_api)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/broker/transport.py", line 45, in _curl
    headers=headers, cainfo=self._pubkey, curl=curl))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/fetch.py", line 113, in fetch
    raise PyCurlError(e.args[0], e.args[1])
PyCurlError: Error 6: Could not resolve host: server-name
2018-06-25 07:31:06,997 INFO     [MainThread] Message exchange failed.
2018-06-25 07:31:06,998 INFO     [MainThread] Message exchange completed in 11.52s.`

Comment: Are you using exact string as above? I mean https://server-name will work if your client can resolved it, if its specified either via local DNS or /etc/hosts file. Can you ping your LDS server  from client that has problems attaching to?  What difference can you see when doing the same on the client that works?

Comment: They can curl each other, but server cannot ping client-name and client cannot ping server name without the .local at the end. Perhaps this is the issue? The one that is working can ping both server-name and client-name just fine, without .local, and is the only of the three devices without a static ip address.

Comment: Seems that you have solved it :) You can add server-name  ip.of.whatever.it.is to client /etc/hosts file and you will have poor man's DNS resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per bogdan's comment above. the solution to my issue was to add a manual entry to /etc.hosts for X.X.X.X server-name on the client computer. Once that was added, not only could I ping server-name without .local, but the registration string from the question worked perfectly.